# forcing invocation of base class method

Tags: java

How does one force to invoke `A`'s `foo()` method when working with instance of `B` (from `main`,  and not through `super` call) ?

I could  **swear** I've seen it done before. Perhaps it was C++ ??

```
public class Test {

    static class A {
        public void foo() {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
    }

    static class B extends A{
        public void foo() {
            System.out.println("B");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        A aa = new B();

        a.foo();
        b.foo();
        ((A)aa).foo(); // want to print A here!
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't. If it's an instance of `B`, then `B.foo()` will be invoked. Additionally, why would you want such a thing? It smells like a violation of the Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza you are just changing the reference of aa object.OP want to cast it

Comment: @TomG Professional curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could swear I've seen it done before. Perhaps it was C++?

The keyword here is [`virtual`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function). This is possible in languages like C++ and C# because it's up to the programmer to define the method as `virtual`. I've adapted this code to C++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
        void foo() {
            std::cout << "A" << endl;
        }
};
class B: public A {
    public:
        void foo() {
            std::cout << "B" << endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    A* a = new A();
    B* b = new B();
    A* aa = new B();
    a->foo();
    b->foo();
    aa->foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
A
B
A
```

Now, using the `virtual` keyword (just posting the relevant code from above example):

```
class A {
    public:
        virtual void foo() {
            std::cout << "A" << endl;
        }
};
```

Prints:

```
A
B
B
```

---

In Java you **cannot** expect this because all methods are `virtual` by default. So, to your question:

> How does one force to invoke `A#foo` when working with instance of `B` and not through `super` call?

In Java, you **can't**.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call the super method in other objects - that would violate encapsulation. The whole point is that the object controls what its overridden methods do. For instance, you might override a collection's add method to throw an exception in certain circumstances, so it could ensure only "valid" items got added to the collection. That would be pointless if callers could just bypass it with a cast!

The only reason an object gets to call super.foo() for itself is to enable one call to be implemented by using the parent implementation. It's up to the code in the class to make sure it only ever does that sensibly. Again, to take the add-in-a-collection example, if the collection overrides add it would have to have some way of adding the validated item to the collection, which it would do with super.add().

Comment: To finish answering the question, in C++ `((A)aa).foo()` will print A unless `foo()` is declared `virtual`. That kind of compile-time overriding is dangerous.

Comment: @Jerry101 the main reason why it is possible in C++ and not in Java is because all methods in Java are `virtual` by default, which is not mentioned in any answer...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes, or to put it stronger, Java doesn't support non-virtual overriding (for good reason).

Answer (score 1):

From outside the class definitions of `A` and `B`, you cannot force the superclass method to run.  `B` has overridden it, so if an `A` reference refers to a `B`, `B`'s `foo` method will run and print `"B"`.  No changes outside of these classes can change this polymorphic behavior -- having an actual `B` object will print `"B"`.

To force it to print `"B"`, you must change code in the `A`/`B` classes.  You can mark `foo` as `final` in `A` so that `B` can't override it.  Optionally, you can optionally include another method call in `A`'s `foo` that `B` can override, so that `A` can guarantee that `"A"` will be printed, but `B` can still do whatever it wants when `foo` is called.

```
static class A {
    public final void foo() {
        System.out.println("A");
        // Optional.
        bar();
    }

    protected void bar() {}
}

static class B extends A {
    // Can't override "foo" now -- can't prevent "A" from being printed.
    //public void foo() {
    //    System.out.println("B");
    //}

    // Optional.
    @Override
    protected void bar() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

Here, `foo` will always print `"A"`, but `B` can also print `"B"` if it really wants.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza How is that "not desired"?  The OP wants to ensure that `A`'s `foo` method is the method called and that `"A"` is printed.  Whether or not `bar` is created, this code ensures that by making `foo` `final` in `A`.

Comment: The question is making variables of type `A` calling `foo` printing `"A"` and keep variables of type `B` printing `"B"` when calling `foo`. This implementation solves one but breaks the other.